# Why didn’t Anakin stay with Padme on Geonosis?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In *Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones* Senator Padme Amidala falls out of a clone [Low Altitude Assault Transport (LAAT) ship](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Low_Altitude_Assault_Transport/infantry) during the Battle of Geonosis. Anakin, of course, wants the ship to land so he can stay with her. Obi-wan then reminds him to “do his duty” and help him kill Count Dooku.

However, Anakin's standing orders and “first priority” from when he and Padme were on Tatooine were to protect the senator at all costs:

> Mace: [to Anakin] Anakin, we will deal with Count Dooku; the most important thing for you is to stay where you are. Protect the Senator at all costs. That is your first priority.
>
> Anakin: Understood, Master.

So, why didn’t Anakin argue that when Obi-wan told him to come with him?

Answer (score 2):

Situations and priorities change. Dooku was about to escape, and Obi-Wan and Anakin were the nearest Jedi.

Padme was relatively safe, away from the battle, and had clone troopers nearby. Even if the fall had hurt Padme, Anakin would not have been much help as he wasn't a healer.

Comment: Not to mention:  the actual command/priority is "Protect the Senator", not "stay with her".  Rushing to her might suggest to the Separatists that there is a high-value target to capture or kill, and Count Dooku was the main threat to her life.  Capturing him, or forcing his retreat, was *at that point in time* the best way to protect her.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember from the beginning, mace windu said we are keepers of the peace not security. This was in response to palpatine asking for protection for padme. Reluctantly the council sent Anakin and obi wan.

Also.. remember padme was being hunted in the first place so she couldn't vote on the military expansion by palpatine. So...

At the end when she falls:

1. She is no longer a target as she is not actively being hunted for in the middle of a war.
2. There are now military soldiers to defend her, so two Jedi are not needed, which now goes along with Mace Windy's statement in the beginning.
3. Unbeknownst to Anakin but Palpstine had no reason to kill her since the military got created. I'm not sure if Anakin and Obi wan knew why she was being hunted to begin with, but this makes her not important. Her being hunted was also to lead Obi wan to the kamino sure to discover the clones.
4. Darth Tyranus (Dooku) was leading the war. His death would've prevented all those clone wars battles seen in Canon. His death was a much higher priority than Padme as thousands of lives could potentially be lost compared to one senator.

5.Padme survived being in an arena with beasts by herself (at least the one attacking her) and defended herself against a few hundred droids along with the Jedi. At this point maybe Obi wan saw that she could take care of herself.

6. Also Anakin was originally  supposed to stay in tattoine. Because he didn't, the plans changed a bit when thrusted into a war